# How set found text in variable in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text string that I want to search for a word.

I need to set a variable to the word found.

My text is `Cat dog Jim NY You`

My search word is `NY`

I need to put the matched substring into a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$x = "Cat dog Jim NY You";

if ( $x=~/NY/ ) {
    print "???\n";
}
```

Comment: I need small example

Comment: Good!
that's what I need

Comment: Just `print "$&\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use captures (`(...)`).

```
if ( my ($capture) = $x =~ /(NY)/ ) {
    say $capture;
}
```

---

By the way, *always* use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`.

The above program also needs `use feature qw( say );`.